# Javascript Jump (show/hide)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Don't have any programming experience and only basic html/css.
I'm trying to create a javascript menu (open to suggestions if there is a easier way?) that will show/hide based on the option selected in the first menu?
I have the following ...

```
<form name="jump"> 
<select name="menu" onChange="location=document.jump.menu.options[document.jump.menu.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO"> 
<option value="#" selected>Quick Links</option>
<option value="menu1">menu1</option> 
<option value="menu2">menu2</option> 
<option value="menu3">menu3</option>
</select>

<select name="menu1" onChange="location=document.jump.menu.options[document.jump.menu.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO"> 
<option value="http://www.site.com/opt1-1.html">opt1</option> 
<option value="http://www.site.com/opt1-2.html">opt2</option> 
<option value="http://www.site.com/opt1-3.html">opt3</option>
</select>

<select name="menu2" onChange="location=document.jump.menu.options[document.jump.menu.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO"> 
<option value="http://www.site.com/opt2-1.html">opt1</option> 
<option value="http://www.site.com/opt2-2.html">opt2</option> 
<option value="http://www.site.com/opt2-3.html">opt3</option>
</select>

<select name="menu3" onChange="location=document.jump.menu.options[document.jump.menu.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO"> 
<option value="http://www.site.com/opt3-1.html">opt1</option> 
<option value="http://www.site.com/opt3-2.html">opt2</option> 
<option value="http://www.site.com/opt3-3.html">opt3</option>
</select>

</form>
```

Can someone explain how i can ....

-show/hide menus 1-2 based on which option is selected in 'menu'???

Thanks inadvance!

Comment: You might want to consider using `<ul>, <li>, and <a>` instead. There are also several third-party tools you may find easier to implement than build from scratch (e.g http://speckyboy.com/2011/07/04/15-fresh-jquery-menu-plugins-and-tutorials/)  "WOW" @jsalonen.  I'm certain you can be more constructive.

Comment: Indeed. Using `select` and `option` is really bad design, something that should be left to the dark shades of the HTML's history.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a ready-made dropdown menu as a solution. Some links:

- 38 jQuery And CSS Drop Down Multi Level Menu Solutions: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/
- 22 Best jQuery Dropdown Menus: http://slodive.com/web-development/best-jquery-dropdown-menus/

Alternatively, you could write your own solutions, say, with jQuery. For more information on this, see for example tutorial for a "[Simple jQuery Dropdown Menu](http://www.webchief.co.uk/blog/simple-jquery-dropdown-menu/index.php)".

Comment: thanks for the advice but i dont think i explained very well. the reason why i need a show and hide style second menu is because the purpose of the 'menus' is a search for a type of product ... for example the first menu will contain makes of car 'Ford', 'mercedes' and 'ferrari' .... if my visitor selected 'ford' i then want to load in a menu that contains the different models of for cars. The jquery menus work to a point but it means i have to have all of the different makes of car (1st menu) on display where really i want them all under one menu? make sense?